# Spring Web MVC :: GET method :: RequestParam encoding

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, rest

I've got a REST entrypoint:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "user" method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<User> getUsers( @RequestParam(value = "name") String name )
```

I'm sending there `/rest/user?name=Иван` using AngularJS, and the request is encoded with `urlencode` in `rest/user?name=%D0%98%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD`.

But the method receives `name` in `ISO_8859_1` charset, not in UTF-8 like expected.
If I write

```
new String(request.getName().getBytes( StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1 ), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
```

it becomes fine. But this is not a correct way :)

**What am I doing wrong and how to fix it?**

===

P. S.

In my web.xml I've got a `CharacterEncodingFilter` configurated for `UTF-8` encoding

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
```

Answer (score -2):

Do you build your project with gradle? Try the flag -Dfile.encoding=utf-8 when you build, the default encoding is the system one

Comment: I use maven, and I have `<encoding>UTF-8</encoding>` in maven-compiler-plugin properties. Also all my files are in UTF-8.

Comment: Well, then try to add 
`<init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
`
to your filter settings

Comment: but I don't need forceEncoding - it will set response encoding then, but the question is about request. See the sources https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/filter/CharacterEncodingFilter.java#L194

Comment: And if you don't add forceEncoding, this filter does nothing

Comment: it doesn't - it sets the request encoding to provided (UTF-8 in my case). See  the sources https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/filter/CharacterEncodingFilter.java#L191
This line is run under debugger.